# Regular expression to extract numbers with either exactly 8 digits or with exactly 7 digits and discard if number have more digits

Tags: regex, excel

I need to extract numbers with either 7 digits or 8 digits exactly from a column in my excel file and need to discard any numbers with more digits.

For example assume these are some of the values

2569123659                               | Extract nothing since > 8 digits

2456789               |    2456789       | Extract 7 digit no

15034891              |    15034891      | Extract 8 digit no

2569123659 45785612   |    45785612      | Extract only 8 digit no

2456789 2569123659    |    2456789       | Extract only 7 digit no

ABC#2456789           |    2456789       | Extract only number

ABC15034891DSC        |    15034891      | Extract only number

ABC15034891###        |    15034891      | Extract only number

The following are some of the expressions I tried

> **strPattern = "[0-9]{7}([0-9]{1})?"**

Results: Wrong result

2569123659            | 2456789

2456789               | 15034891

15034891              | 25691236

2569123659 45785612   | 2456789

2456789 2569123659    |  2456789

ABC#2456789           |    2456789

ABC15034891DSC        |    15034891

ABC15034891###        |    15034891

> **strPattern = "(\d{8}|\d{7})"**

Results: Still Wrong result

2569123659            | 25691236

2456789               | 2456789

15034891              | 15034891

2569123659 45785612   | 25691236

2456789 2569123659    | 2456789

ABC#2456789           |    2456789

ABC15034891DSC        |    15034891

ABC15034891###        |    15034891

Help me rectify this reg expression so as to handle the scenario. I need to extract only the correct number. I need to avoid the extraction from another no with more digits.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

---

Based on answers provided here I also tried

> **strPattern = "\b(\d{7,8})\b"**

Results: Still Wrong result

2569123659            |

2456789               | 2456789

15034891              | 15034891

2569123659 45785612   | 45785612

2456789 2569123659    | 2456789

ABC#2456789           |

ABC15034891DSC        |

ABC15034891###        |

Still not accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
(?:^|\D)(\d{7,8})(?!\d)
```

Your 7 or 8 digit number will be in `.Submatches(0)`.

The `(?:^|\D)` matches either start of string or a non-digit and the negative lookahead `(?!\d)` fails the match if a digit is found immediately to the right after seven or eight digit number.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/6Hnyym/1).

See an example code:

```
Sub GetResults()
Dim rExp As Object, allMatches As Object, match As Object
Dim text As String

text = "ABC15034891###"

Set rExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With rExp
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .pattern = "(?:^|\D)(\d{7,8})(?!\d)"
End With


Set allMatches = rExp.Execute(text)
For Each match In allMatches
    Debug.Print(match.SubMatches.Item(0))
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Stribizew Thanks but that doesnt work on the following cases ABC#2456789
ABC15034891DSC        
ABC15034891###

Comment: @eccentricCoder [It works ver well for these cases](https://regex101.com/r/AuH2zo/1/).

Comment: For the above mentioned cases, it returns the number along with the # or alphabet appended to it for  eg for ABC#2456789  it returns ABC#2456789 , for ABC15034891DSC  it returns C15034891 and for ABC15034891### it returns C15034891

Comment: I tried with (?:\b)\b(\d{7,8})\b it is working for all the cases except ABC1234567,
ABC1234567#, and
ABC1503481DSC

Comment: @eccentricCoder You are getting the preceding non-digit (when using the original regex code) because you are returning the **entire match**.  The answer clearly states that the digits will be in **`.Submatches(0)`**.

Comment: I wrote: the result you need is inside `Submatches(0)`. I added a sample Sub.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot! It worked. Sorry for not getting it the first time. Understood it now.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thankyou. I understood it now.

Answer (score 1):

**Try `\D(\d{7,8})\D` :**

```
\b -> word boundary 
\d -> digit [0-9]
\D -> non digit
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/2R5HRN/2

Comment: I wonder if the OP wants to extract the seven digit number from `abc1234567def`?

Comment: @Ashraful Islam Thanks a lot, that does solve my problem.

Comment: @eccentricCoder Now i grouped the number, so that you can access it with `$1`

Comment: @Ashraful Islam Thankyou. I tried the new expression but it doesnt help me extract the 8 digit number. Also what should be done if I need to extract 1234567 out of abc1234567def. Sorry for asking but I am completely new to regular expressions.

Comment: @eccentricCoder which programming language are you using ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I tried \D(\d{7,8})\b but that also doesnt produce the required result. I am using VB (for excel macros)

Comment: Try `\D(\d{7,8})\D`

Comment: @AshrafulIslam That doesnt work for the following cases --> ABC#2456789
ABC15034891 and 2456789 2569123659
Here 2456789, 15034891,  2456789 should be extracted respectively. expression **\b(\d{7,8})\b ** works for all the cases except ABC15034891